# Get total size of attached files on all list items in SharePoint 2007with PowerShell v2.0

Tags: 2007, powershell

Using Powershell, I have to get the total size of all attached files on all list items for a generic list. I tried using the function below but this displays the total length of names for the attached files.

```
function GetListSize($List)
{
    [long]$listSize = 0                 

    foreach ($listItem in $List.Items)
    {                   
        $listItemAttachments = $listItem.Attachments 
        foreach($file in $listItemAttachments) 
        {            
            $listSize +=  $file.Length 
        }
    }

    $totalInMb = ($listSize/1024)/1024
    $totalInMb = "{0:N2}" -f $totalInMb

    return $totalInMb    
}
```

I can do this using C# code ([How to get size of SharePoint 2010 list item attachment?](http://mykiavash.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/how-to-get-size-of-sharepoint-2010-list-item-attachment/)). How can I do this using Powershell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SPAttachmentCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spattachmentcollection.aspx) stores only file names. To get actual files, you should retrieve files with these names from folder `$List.RootFolder.SubFolders["Attachments"].SubFolders[$listItem.ID]`.

So, you should use this code:

```
function GetListSize($List)
{
    [long]$listSize = 0
    $allAttachmentsFolder = $List.RootFolder.SubFolders["Attachments"]

    foreach ($listItem in $List.Items)
    {                   
        $listItemAttachments = $listItem.Attachments
        $attachmentsFolder = $allAttachmentsFolder.SubFolders[$listItem.ID]
        foreach($file in $listItemAttachments) 
        {            
            $listSize += $attachmentsFolder.Files[$file].Length
        }
    }

    $totalInMb = ($listSize/1024)/1024
    $totalInMb = "{0:N2}" -f $totalInMb

    return $totalInMb    
}
```

Comment: eh, thx I will test it now...

Comment: I think, you even could try to walk through all the $list.RootFolder.SubFolders["Attachments"].SubFolders, and count all files size in each of them. This should be a little bit faster.

Comment: I receive an error on this line $allAttachmentsFolder = $List.RootFolder.SubFolder[ <<<< "Attachments"] but anyway I made it work using this $attachmentsFolder = $Web.Folders["Lists"].SubFolders[$list.Title].SubFolders["Attachments"].SubFolders[$listItem.Id] and of cource I send the Web as parameter to the function also ... I will try your last suggestion also. THX

Comment: ok, fix it the correct line was $allAttachmentsFolder = $List.RootFolder.SubFolders["Attachments"] aka SubFolers instead of SubFolder :) BIG THX

Comment: I fixed the answer, it was a kind of typo, sorry :( P.S. You should upvote and accept the answer if it helped you, to make people see that it is correct.

Comment: to check the size using the interface  http://msmvps.com/blogs/shane/archive/2008/06/20/list-size-reporting.aspx